# Unable to insert to Child Table in reference of a Parent Table in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with my code base or on my database since i was just trying to insert a device information to a table in reference to the user who owns it. no errors are being thrown but the device registration isn't working.

Here's the database

```
      CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `email` varchar(255),
      `password` varchar(255),
      `firstname` varchar(255),
      `lastname` varchar(255),
      `dob` varchar(255),
      `country` varchar(255),
      `farmname` varchar(255),
      `acctype` varchar(255),
      `firmware` double
       );
    
        CREATE TABLE `controlModules` (
      `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `deviceowner` int,
      `devicename` varchar(255),
      `serial#` varchar(255),
      `devicestate` varchar(255),
      `ipaddress` varchar(255),
      `wanaddress` varchar(255),
      `firmware` varchar(255)
    );

ALTER TABLE `controlModules` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`deviceowner`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

Here's the function for react.js where it passes input data to backend

```
const email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
const [name, setDeviceName] = useState("");
const [serial, setDeviceSerial] = useState("");
const [lanip, setDeviceLANIP] = useState("");
const [wanip, setDeviceWANIP] = useState("");

const [deviceStatus, setDeviceStatus] = useState("");

Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const registerDevice =()=>{
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3020/registerDevice", {
      email: email,
      name: name,
      serial: serial,
      lanip: lanip,
      wanip: wanip,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        setDeviceStatus(response);
      } else {
        setDeviceStatus("error");
      }
    }); 
};
```

Here's the code for backend on node.js

```
app.post("/registerDevice", (req, res)=> {
const email = req.body.email;
const name = req.body.name;
const serial = req.body.serial;
const lanip = req.body.lanip;
const wanip = req.body.wanip;
const status = "online"
const firmware = "1.3";

console.log(email);

let stmt = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?`;
let todo = [email];

//getting parentid
db.query(stmt, todo, (err, results, fields) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log(results)
  const userid = results.id;

  let statement = `INSERT INTO controlModules(deviceowner, devicename, serial#, devicestate, ipaddress, wanaddress, firmware) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)`;
  let task = [userid, name, serial, status, lanip, wanip, firmware];
  
  //inserting to childtable
  db.query(statement, task, (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

Thanks for the help and enlightenment.

Comment: why use # at your column name?

Comment: You query the users table using the id column, then retrieve the id column's value from the resultset and use that in the insert statement. I'm sorry, but this does not make any sense at all! If you already know the user id, then you do not need to query it, just use it in your insert statement directly.